# Unable to load assembly in Assembly.LoadFrom method

Tags: c#, winforms

I am facing a problem while loading a assembly using `Assembly.LoadFrom` method. Following is the code.

```
Assembly theAssembly = default(Assembly);
string PathOfAssembly="C:\\Myapplication\\BasicACHTransmitters.dll";
//Load the assembly into memory
theAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(PathOfAssembly);
```

in the last line `theAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(PathOfAssembly)` I am getting following error.

> Unable to load assembly BasicACHTransmitters   at M3.AKAP.frmACHSetUp.LoadClasss.LoadClass(String AssemblyName, String ClassName, String InterfaceRequired) in c:\Builds\1\AccKnowledge\AK3-QA-LS5-Manual\Sources\AccKnowledge\Code\Ack3.0-QA\UI\M3.AKAP\frmACHSetUp.cs:line 522.

I am unable to find the solution of this and I am stuck now. Please help me to resolve this problem. Any help will appreciated.

**Note: The same code is working successfully on another machine with same assembly.**

Comment: Is "BasicACHTransmitters" a .net assembly?

Comment: Is the file present at the given location?

Comment: 1. You do not have to assign `theAssembly` with `default(Assembly)` in your code snippet. 2. Other of yours code looks OK - so something wrong is with your assembly - check references and whether you can load DLL - you can verify it with [NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) for example. Also to have this fixed - please provide more information about error you get.

Comment: @Chilaka Umesh, Yes this is a .net assembly.

Comment: @Andrii Kalytiiuk. i will do this change but this same code is working on another machine.

Comment: Are you running with elevated permissions on both machines?

Comment: Yes, Both machine have elevated permissions. i have verified.

Comment: @TikamSangwani Can you load assembly with *Visual Studio Object Browser* or *.NET Reflector* or use it when referenced directly on first machine - where code does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link using Reflection method.
[Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a)

Answer (score 0):

1.) Try open the file using a reflector tool like [just decompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)

I would assume the file isn't a .net assembly

2.) If it is a assembly check wether you have the permissions to access the file. 
If it is a .net policy prevent access and not a windows permission you can Use [Caspol.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz.aspx) to make the file trustworthy 
For example:

```
caspol -machine -addfulltrust Z:\myNetworkAssembly.dll
```